# o365 PowerApps Cosmos DB connector asking for Account ID and Key?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, powerapps

I just get "something went wrong".  What is it looking for?

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to show actual detail? Right now, there's nothing telling us what, exactly, you're referring to. Are you saying you don't know where to find the account name & key for your Cosmos DB database? Also, "*tried everything I can find in Azure*" really isn't helpful for those trying to help you. I removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Account Id should be the name of the account that you created: if your host name is `mycosmosdb.documents.azure.net`, then the account id is `mycosmosdb`.

The key is one of the passwords that you can find in the settings page (I was able to create a connection using one I got in the connection strings tab) on the Azure portal.